# 4Gb sd recognized as 1.6Gb

Tags: 12.04, sd-card, arm

I used as dd command to make my 4GB sd card bootable for arch linux arm as explained [here](http://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv5/olinuxino) since it didn't work I tried formatting the card in my ubuntu again but now it recognizes it as a 1.6GB card and a 32MB card. 
Is there any way I can restore my card?

Answer (score 1):

The `dd` command has the effect of creating whatever partition or partitions are in the image file you start with (i.e., the file given after `if=`). Those partitions' sizes are *not* determined by the size of the disk being written to (i.e., the disk specified after `of=`). When the disk is larger than necessary, it will have unpartitioned space after being written to with `dd`. Reformatting the partitions that already exist does not change their size and consequently will not make the extra space accessible.

Repartitioning the SD card is the solution. Install the [gparted [image: Install gparted]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gparted) package.  **Assuming there is nothing of any value on the SD card**, you can use GParted to delete the existing partitions (or to create a new partition table, which will get rid of them too). After the `gparted` package is installed you can run GParted by typing it into the dash (press the Super/Windows key or click the home button on the upper-*left* corner of the screen, then start typing in `gparted` until the GParted icon appears; then click on it).

**Make sure you are editing the partitions on the SD card, and not on some other drive; if you accidentally perform actions on the wrong drive with GParted, you could experience great data loss.** (And if you ever *do* need to modify the partitions on the physical disk that contains the running Ubuntu system, it's not safe to run GParted from the system on that disk to do that. Instead, for *that purpose*, you must run GParted from a live CD/DVD/USB instead.)

To make sure you're on the SD card and not some other device, select in from the drop-down menu at the upper-right corner of the GParted window. Make sure its partitions are the same size and type as you expected. An SD card will typically be called `/dev/mmcblkN`, where `N` is a number (usually `0`, if you only have one SD card). The device names for the partitions on an SD card called `/dev/mmcblk0` are called `/dev/mmcblk0p1`, `/dev/mmcblk0p2`, and so forth. You can verify that the drive name takes the form `/dev/mmcblkN` in the drop-down menu where you select it, and also that its partitions are listed as the device name with `pN` appended.

Once you've verified that you're working on the right disk, create whatever partition(s) you want. **If you want one big partition, create one, of whatever partition type you prefer.** (Most SD cards are formatted FAT32.)

Answer (score 0):

Open disk utility in ubuntu to view, modify and configure disks and media. Just unmount it first before formatting. Hope it help!

Comment: im actually not that familiar with linux can you explain how? thank you

Comment: I'm newbie also.It's the easy and simple way. Just follow the interface. I'm also had the same problem with my pendrive, I had 4GB but it detect as 1 GB. When i check through 'disk' utility, it has partition that not been formatted due to BAD formatting. Just reminder to unmount the sd card first, if not formatting will be corrupted. Thanks.